$\ell^{p}(I, Z \oplus Y) \approx \ell^{p}(I, Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$
In "The decomposition technique" by Pełczynski one uses that
$\ell^{p}(I, Z \oplus Y) \approx \ell^{p}(I, Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$
where $\ell^p(I,X)$ is the infinite direct sum formed by the Index set $I$ ($=\mathbb{N}$ in this case) and a Banach space $X$. I use $V$ $\approx$ $W$ for $V$ and $W$ isomorph. In the theorem this relation is used as a trivial fact. Nevertheless for me it appears not that trivial. What is the isomorphism between this two spaces and how can I prove it. I have already learnt that one can split the index set: $X \approx \ell^p(I,X)$ $\Rightarrow$ $X \approx X \oplus X$ (used in The Pełczynski decomposition technique) . But for the case of the space this seems like a different type of argument.

Isn't this the commutativity and associativity of direct sums?

I am not aware of if this property extends to the infinte direct sum case.  But for the finite case I agree with you. Or do I understand something wrong.

Note that if $Z$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then you have the projections $p_{Z}:Z\oplus Y \to Z$ and $p_{Y}:Z\oplus Y\to Y$ defined by $p_{Z}(z,y) := z$ and $p_{Y}(z,y) := y$ respectively. You also have the injections $i_{Z}:Z\to Z\oplus Y$ and $i_{Y}:Y\to Z\oplus Y$ defined by $i_{Z}(z) := (z,0)$ and $i_{Y}(y) := (0,y)$ respectively. Note that all of these maps are continuous as maps from one Banach space into another.
If you have $f\in \ell^{p}(I, Z\oplus Y)$, then $p_{Z}\circ f \in \ell^{p}(I,Z)$ and $p_{Y}\circ f \in \ell^{p}(I, Y)$. So given $f\in \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$, it can be associated with $(p_{Z} \circ f, p_{Y}\circ f) \in \ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$. Conversely, given $f\in \ell^{p}(I,Z)$ and $g\in \ell^{p}(I,Y)$, then $i_{Z}\circ f \in \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$ and $i_{Y}\circ g \in \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$. Then you have $(i_{Z} \circ f) + (i_{Y} \circ g) \in \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$. So given $(f,g) \in \ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$, it can be associated with $(i_{Z}\circ f) + (i_{Y}\circ g) \in \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$.
Preceding from the discussion above, if you define $\phi :\ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y) \to \ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$ by $\phi (f) := (i_{Z}\circ f, i_{Y}\circ f)$, this can be verified to be a continuous linear bijection of $\ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$ onto $\ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$. This automatically has a continuous inverse by the bounded inverse theorem and is consequently a linear homeomorphism of $\ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$ onto $\ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)$. However, the inverse can be explicitly given by the linear map $\psi :\ell^{p}(I,Z) \oplus \ell^{p}(I,Y)\to \ell^{p}(I,Z\oplus Y)$ defined by $\psi (f,g) := (i_{Z}\circ f) + (i_{Y}\circ g)$.

thank you very much, I genuinely appreciate your help while diving into this new world. I have never heard of the bounded inverse problem but it seems to be equivalent to the open mapping theorem right?

No problem. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. The open mapping theorem states that if a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ is surjective, then it is an open map, so that it maps open sets onto open sets. The bounded inverse theorem states that if any continuous bijective linear operator $T:X\to Y$ has a continuous inverse, so that it is automatically a linear homeomorphism of $X$ onto $Y$. The bounded inverse theorem is typically obtained as a corollary to the open mapping theorem.

Does this also extend if the direct sum in the infinite direct sum is also an infinte direct sum. I mean that $\ell^{p} (I, \ell^{p}(I,Y)) \approx \ell^{p} (I, \ell^{p}(I,Y)) \oplus Y$

Did you intend to use a different expression than the one you wrote up? It doesn't look like it is the same one you were talking about. I'm not sure about whether the isomorphism you wrote there is valid, so I'll have to think about it.

I think our notation is the same or what is not clear?

You were talking about an infinite direct sum, but I'm not sure where $Y$ came from in the expression $\ell^{p}(I,\ell^{p}(I,Y))\oplus Y$. It isn't immediately clear how this is an extension of the question you previously asked.
